# Filemaker 13 Quicklook Script

Tags: applescript, filemaker, osx-yosemite

Running Filemaker 13 on Mac OSX Yosemite. 
We have a quicklook script that has, up until Yosemite, worked without issue.  Normally, it takes a .doc/.docx file in the container field and opens it up in Quicklook.

However in Yosemite, it opens qlmanage, then causes Filemaker to freeze and crash.

```
Set Variable [ $file ; Value: ${database}::Container Field ]
Set Variable [ $path ; Value: Get ( Temporary Path ) & $file ]
Set Variable [ $script ; Value:
  Let (
    thepath = Middle( $path ; Position ($path ; "/" ; 1 ; 2 ); Length ($path) ;
    "set p to POSIX path of " & Quote (thepath) &
    "¶ do shell script \"qlmanage -p \" & quoted form of p" )
]
Export Field Contents [Database::Container Field ; "$path" ]
Perform Applescript [ $script ]
```

Can anyone give me some ideas on what might be going wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: The script looks fine, but I would begin troubleshooting by checking the value of `$script` after that third line and making sure it looks right, then confirming that by actually executing the `$script` code in Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded with an edited version of your script using FileMaker Pro Advanced 14.0.2 running under OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 in a demo file that looked like this:

```
Set Variable [ $_file ; Value: GetAsText ( Table::container ) ]
Set Variable [ $_fm_path ; Value: Get ( TemporaryPath ) & $_file ]
Set Variable [ $_as_path ; Value: Middle (
    $_fm_path;
    Position ( $_fm_path; "/" ; 1 ; 2 ) ;
    Length ( $_fm_path) )
]
Set Variable [ $_script ; Value: List (
    "set p to POSIX path of " & Quote ( $_as_path ) ;
    "do shell script \"qlmanage -p \" & quoted form of p" )
]

Export Field Contents [ Table::container ; “$_fm_path” ]
Perform AppleScript [ $_script ]

Exit Script []
```

The primary differences between this and what you showed are:

- I used a direct reference to the table name. I'm actually not sure what `${database}` refers to. Perhaps `Get ( FileName )`?
- I stored the AppleScript path in a variable for easier debugging.

If this doesn't work, I'd work with the recommendation I gave about testing the execution of the contents of `$_script` in **Script Editor** and the contents of the shell's `p` variable in **Terminal**.